# Change Div Content after 10 secs

Tags: jquery, css

How can I make a slider of text moving in it..

At firsty it shows some text and after some time it may show some other text. How can I do this with jQuery and CSS?

Comment: see this[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398526/javascript-jquery-or-something-to-change-text-every-some-seconds)

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: use `setInterval()` and jQ's `.animate()` function. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question will be closed (I have voted to close myself). But to get you started, try using something like this..

```
setInterval(function(){

    $('#slider').html(new Date());

},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

put it in

```
setTimeout(function(){

    //Your code here

},10000);
```