# How to use SetInterval and SetText functions to dynamically change a text field automatically

Tags: javascript

I know very little about coding (beyond variable setting and some concepts). I have an entertainment presentation with a text field within it that I want to change every 1/2 second or so.

[javascript / jquery or something to change text every some seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398526/javascript-jquery-or-something-to-change-text-every-some-seconds)

This helps some, but the presentation program states it requires the SetText program. I've tried this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   SetText('awesome','incredible','whatever');
}, 1000);
```

This works but only adds "awesome" or the first word in the string. How can I set it so that it changes to other words at the given interval rate?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the `SetText` program? A code sample or documentation would be ideal.

Comment: Try passing an array for the setText argument later with a random function select the position of the array

Comment: The program I'm using is called XSplit--it's specifically a program designed for broadcasting video game streaming presentations, but it can also utilize Javascript to do neater stuff. The text field properties in question state this:

/* Javascript knowledge is required when using the blank template of the custom script.
You will need to call SetText(string) in order to change the text in XSplit Broadcaster Mixer. */

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in code? Some of the terms are honestly over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `SetText` function only accepts one parameter, so the other two don't have any effect.

What you can do is create an array of words, and on every iteration change the index.

```
// List of words to loop on
var words = ['awesome','incredible','whatever'];

// Index of the words array
var index = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
  SetText(words[index]);
  // Increment the index modulo the length of words: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, etc
  index = (index+1) % words.length;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!